# adding page number to barcodes

Tags: isbn

I do genealogy research.  I have books with information on many pages.  Is there a way for me to use the book isbn and associate it with a particular page?  I may find many references to different individuals in the same book.  I copy the page, but would like to be able to print the isbn number of the source and include the page number.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

I think your going to have to clarify your question preferably with some code showing what you have so far. Barcodes are just serial numbers, there is no reason you can't combine the ISBN + page number into a barcode and print it out.